# Laravel persist $request->flash old() session

Tags: forms, laravel, session

So, I've build in functionality which redirects the logged in user to a pincode screen after 10 minutes of inactivity, when the user enters the correct pincode he or she is redirected to the page where he or she was navigating to.. So far so good but...

Imagine the user is filling out a form and waits ten minutes before hitting the submit button and is then redirected to the pincode page, after inputting the correct pincode he is on the form again but all data on it is gone.

What I want is to remember all the filled data, I've tried it via the old() method but that only persists for one request.

**PincodeCheck Middleware**

```
if($difference_in_minutes > config('pincode.lifetime')) {
    return redirect()->route('pincode')->withInput();
}
```

**PincodeController**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // $request->old() is holding the values
    return view('pincode.index');
}

public function unlock(Request $request)
{
    // This is the after submit function, $request->old() is empty here
    if(Hash::check($request->pincode, auth()->user()->pincode) == true) {
        $request->session()->put('pincode-timestamp', date('U'));

        $path = config('app.homeroute');

        if($request->session()->has('intended.get.path')) {
            $path = $request->session()->get('intended.get.path');
        }

        return redirect($path);
    }

    return redirect()->route('pincode');
}
```

Comment: You would have to send the data to the server constantly using ajax for example and keep this data in the session. The `old()` method will not work because the form was never sent to the server.

Comment: Well I can output the old() data in the index() method of the controller, I'm looking for a way to persist it after I redirect to the intended page again.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?